# Proper scrollbar setup on html element

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I have a header and a sidebar with form. On the form I wish to have a scroll bar when the form is larger then screen.

Here is html with inline style for the form:

```
<body>
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="header" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top"></div>
    <div id="wrapper" class="toggled">
        <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
            <div id="sidebar-content">
                <form id="my-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" style="width: 235px; overflow-y: auto;height: 100%;position: absolute">
                    <label>Dropdown 1
                        <select id="select1"></select>
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        Dropdown 2
                        <select id="select2"></select>
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        Dropdown 3
                        <select id="select3"></select>
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        Dropdown 4
                        <select id="select4"></select>
                    </label>
                    <button class="btn btn-success btn-default">Submit</button>
                </form>

            </div>
            <a class="ToggleSidebar" href="#"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

[And here is JSfiddle with my approach so far.](https://jsfiddle.net/kefahuchi/v7y9ghvz/)

The problem is that my scroll-bar appears only when I shrunk page above about the beginning of last drop-down and become useless, because I am not able to reach the button. And I really wish it to appear as soon as I shrink above button and make it scroollable to whole button.

Comment: Why you use `position:fixed` and `position:absolute` for simple form. Please try to avoid if not required.

Comment: I have no idea why, but when I don't use position fixed or absolute on that form, the scrollbar will never even appear. And about fixed for that sidebar wrapper, that fiddle is just simplified version of more complicated page/application. The sidebar is collapsible and I could't make it work without absolute position. But if you can give me  some alternate working approach I will be very grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `height:100%` for the sidebar and add `top:60px, bottom:0px;`
Also, you don't need another position fixed for the wrapper, you can just add that top 60px or you can add a padding-top for the wrapper, but that is your choise.

See a working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/v7y9ghvz/4/

Comment: Great, thank you, I am sending you a virtual beer for this. I am just little confused. I thought, that when I have top:60px on parent element, its child will be top:60px as well. It is because that height 100% is calculated from top of the page not 60px below the top of the page? Please explain me this, if you just can spend few more seconds with me.

Comment: If you add 100% height to a fix element, it will be 100% of the window. If you also add a top position, it will go under the visible area... A fixed element will always be relative to the window.